# VSeWSS 1.3 created web part solution not adding SafeControl entries

Tags: sharepoint, vsewss

We have several VSeWSS 1.3 projects that add web parts to SharePoint. We have a problem with one of the projects in that it does not add SafeControl entriees for the web parts when deploying. It also deploys the solution Global. I have looked add the solution file but can't find anything there that is different from the other projects. The solution is adding things in the Template folder.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the project had a referane to an other sharepoint project. This made sharepoint look at this solution as a global solution. Removing the referance fixed the problem.